# how to create a pandas.dataframe of a json with values in a list with no key in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this json:

```
{
"columns": [
    {
        "field": "date",
        "name": "Date",
        "type": "dim"
    },
    {
        "field": "adsetstart_time",
        "name": "Ad set start time",
        "type": "dim"
    },
    {
        "field": "adsetend_time",
        "name": "Ad set end time",
        "type": "dim"
    },
    {
        "field": "adcampaign_id",
        "name": "Campaign ID",
        "type": "dim"
    },
    {
        "field": "cost",
        "name": "Amount spent",
        "type": "met"
    }
],
"data": [
    [
        "2017-10-21",
        "2017-10-02",
        "2017-11-01",
        "6076466058814",
        81.32
    ],
    [
        "2017-10-21",
        "2017-10-04",
        "2017-11-01",
        "6076547852614",
        47.46
    ],
    [
        "2017-10-21",
        "2017-10-04",
        "2017-11-01",
        "6076549546014",
        128.58
    ]
],
"notes": {
    "datasource": "FA",
    "numeric_format_columns_start": 4,
    "numeric_format_rows_start": 0,
    "result_rows": 50,
    "result_values": 250,
    "runtime_sec": 3,
    "status": "success"
}
}
```

and I want this table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PFWS.png)

I'm new to programming, I tried to modify the `dictionary` structure by creating a new one with the keys-value inside `data` like this:

```
{"data": ["Date": "2017-10-24", "Ad set start time": "2017-10-16", "Ad set end time": "2017-10-27", "Campaign ID": "6076811156014", "Amount spent": 106.84],...
```

I managed to extract the columns in a list but I can not iterate `data` to assign each value its corresponding key.

What is the best way to create the dataframe from this json structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# data = dict provided in OP
colnames = [x["name"] for x in data["columns"]]
pd.DataFrame(data["data"], columns=colnames)

         Date Ad set start time Ad set end time    Campaign ID  Amount spent
0  2017-10-21        2017-10-02      2017-11-01  6076466058814         81.32
1  2017-10-21        2017-10-04      2017-11-01  6076547852614         47.46
2  2017-10-21        2017-10-04      2017-11-01  6076549546014        128.58
```

Answer (score 0):

First read the json object, extract the columns, and then use the data and columns within a DataFrame constructor.

```
import json

with open('jsonfile.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f)

columns = [field['name'] for field in data['columns']]

pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=columns)
```